# Changing text in UIWebView with the press of a button. (simple?)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uibutton

How can I change the text in a WebView, with the press of a button?

I have a Web View, populated with HTML.

```
if ([buttonState isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
    UIFont *webFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    NSString *mainTextString;
    mainTextString = @"<p><b>General:</b>THIS IS TEXT1</p>";
    mainTextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: %@; font-size: %i\">%@</span>", webFont.fontName, (int) webFont.pointSize, mainTextString];
    [mainText loadHTMLString:mainTextString baseURL:nil];
}
else if ([buttonState isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
    UIFont *webFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    NSString *mainTextString;
    mainTextString = @"<p><b>General:</b>THIS IS TEXT2</p>";
    mainTextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: %@; font-size: %i\">%@</span>", webFont.fontName, (int) webFont.pointSize, mainTextString];
    [mainText loadHTMLString:mainTextString baseURL:nil];
}
```

I also have a UIButton, with which I want to change the text in the Webview.

```
- (IBAction)textChangeButton:(id)sender {
    if ([buttonState isEqualToString: @"NO"]) {
        buttonState = @"YES";
    }
    else if ([buttonState isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        buttonState = @"NO";
    }
    [mainText reload];
}
```

Unfortunately, when I press the button the second text does not appear!

Being fairly new to programming, I have no idea what the problem is. I have tried reloading the webview in the button press - still no luck. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Since you're using a string flag `buttonState`, make sure to set the initial value to `@"NO"`, or better use a `BOOL` flag that will hold the value `NO` initially. And reload the webview for sure.

Comment: Hi Hejazi, thanks for your comment. The initial value for buttonState was @"YES". Sorry I wasn't more clear in my original post, which I will amend now: when I click the button, the web view just becomes blank (the first text disappears, and the second does not appear). I am reloading the webview in the button - but still nothing. Any more suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By reloading the webview I mean to execute the first code above again. Calling `[mainText reload]` will just load an empty page.

Comment: This is exactly my problem then! The first piece of code is in viewdidload, a)how can I go about calling it again? b) Im guessing calling viewdidload will cause the whole page to reload? Thanks for helping out an amateur Hejazi!

Comment: Just move that code to a new method (`reloadWebPage` for example) and call it in `viewDidLoad` and `textChangeButton:`.

Comment: Your spot on, thank you so much for your help - totally pointed me in the right direction! I will try that out tomorrow!

Comment: I'll move this to an answer so you can accept it if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `[mainText reload]` will just load an empty page. You need to execute the first code again for the webview to load the correct content.

Try to move the code to a new method and call it in `viewDidLoad` and `textChangeButton:`

```
- (void)reloadWebPage {
    if ([buttonState isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        mainTextString = (...);
        [mainText loadHTMLString:mainTextString baseURL:nil];
    }
    else if ([buttonState isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
        mainTextString = (...);
        [mainText loadHTMLString:mainTextString baseURL:nil];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self reloadWebPage];
}

- (IBAction)textChangeButton:(id)sender {
    if ([buttonState isEqualToString: @"NO"]) {
        buttonState = @"YES";
    }
    else if ([buttonState isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        buttonState = @"NO";
    }

    [self reloadWebPage];
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I can't believe I didn't work it out myself! Thank you for your help.